# PyCharm auto-imports ignore Django project name

Tags: django, pycharm

PyCharm allows you to auto-import a class that is not found... So for instance if I typed a method name or class name, that is not found in the current file, PyCharm can automatically add an import statement for it. However, the problem is that the auto-import misses the current Django projects name...

So for example:

Your Django project is called **myproject**, and the current application is **myapp**. You have a class in your **models.py** called **MyModel**.

If you type in "**MyModel**" somewhere, the automatically generated import statement will be:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
```

I however want it to be:

```
from myproject.myapp.models import MyModel
```

Does anyone have any idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It`s a bad practice to include project name into imports. It makes harder to reuse your app. And you cannot easily change project name if you want to. Some hostings like ep.io even requires to not use a project name in imports. And afaik you cannot change such import behavoiur in PyCharm. You can try to fill a request at their [bugtracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/PY), but i doudt that it will be implemented.

Comment: Your argument has merit, I'm just worried about polluting the namespace, but I guess I should just use more unique App names? Then again, I looked at Django examples and they also seem to import only the app name, rather than the project.app name. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems that my optimism was premature. Importing the app names directly proved to be a risky proposition, especially if one happened to use app names that were not unique. For instance I have an app called sync, also a file called sync in every app. Bad choice perhaps, nonetheless it forces me to import all my sync modules and sync files with the project_name.sync, the problem comes when you try to catch exceptions, and they are not recognized because you've accidentally mixed **from project_name.foo import ...** with just **from foo import ...**. A nightmare is created!